# cakePHP afterFind() Warning (2)

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a problem in my application the problem is in the afterFind() function,
Here's the code:

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false){
    App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
    $deplacement_id = CakeSession::read('id-deplacement');

    foreach($results as $k=>$valeur){
        $results[$k][$this->alias]['checked']='false';
        foreach($valeur['Realisation'] as $v=> $val){
            if($val['deplacement_id'] == $deplacement_id){
                $results[$k][$this->alias]['checked'] = 'true';
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

The code works fine if I test the $results variable with debug() in the model it shows me what I want to have but the problem comes from the View this is the error:

```
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\Model\Pointerne.php, line 46]

Notice (8): Undefined index: Realisation [APP\Model\Pointerne.php, line 46]
```

I deleted the error if I may debug() in the core file a 0 but so I can not use the debug function for for testing my variable.

thank you for your help

Comment: check whether $valeur['Realisation'] is set or not.

Comment: You don't "delete" errors be setting debug to 0, you suppress, hide, them. Even notices should be fixed and not suppressed if not that's pretty bad coding.

Comment: I know it is coded male but I put in the foreach directly in my Controller this is the same treatment but I know I did not meet the standards of CakePhp, thank you for your help